# Spring AOP - Intercepting a class that its ancestor has an annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have the following hierarchy:

```
@Validated
public class BaseResource
```

and

```
public class DeviceResource extends BaseResource
```

The `@Validated` annotation is as follows:

```
package com.redbend.validation.annotation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.inject.Scope;



@Scope
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface Validated {

}
```

And I have a Spring Aspect with the following advice:

```
    package com.redbend.validation.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.redbend.exceptions.EExceptionMsgID;
import com.redbend.exceptions.runtime.MissingMandatoryParameterException;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.MandatoryOneOfParams;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.MandatoryParams;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.NotEmpty;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.OneOfParamsForValue;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.OneOfParamsForValueMap;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.ParamsForValue;
import com.redbend.validation.annotation.ParamsForValueMap;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(2)


public class ValidationInterceptor {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidationInterceptor.class);

    public ValidationInterceptor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Before("within(com.redbend..*) && @within(com.redbend.validation.annotation.Validated) ")
    public void validate(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
        validateParams(joinPoint);
    }
```

When I call a method in `DeviceResource`, it is not caught by the aspect, even thought it inherits from `BaseResource` which is annotated with `@Validated`, and `@Validated` is annotated with `@Inherited`.
When I annotate `DeviceResource` with `@Validated` it works fine. How can I make the aspect intercept my method in `DeviceResource` without annotating it with `@Validated`?

Thanks,

Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it by changing the pointcut expression in my aspect:

```
@Before("within(com.redbend..*) && within(@com.redbend.validation.annotation.Validated *)")
```

I still don't know why it didn't work before or why `@within(com.redbend.validation.annotation.Validated)`
didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

```
within(@com.redbend.validation.annotation.Validated)
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
@within(com.redbend.validation.annotation.Validated)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I get the following error: error Type referred to is not an annotation type: com$redbend$validation$annotation$Validated

Comment: You should make it an annotation then :) Could you share the Validated class as it is (including the package declaration)? (I've tested the thing I wrote, so it _will_ work)
My annotation was like this:
`package hu.bbako.ecm;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InheritableAnnotation {
}`

Comment: I've changed 1 thing in your annotation and it worked. I don't have the javax.inject.Scope on my ClasssPath, so I used `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;`

Comment: I removed the Scope, and still doesn't work... I posted my aspect class, maybe I did something wrong there...

Comment: Same error as before (`com$redbend$validation$annotation$Validated` )? You probably need a clean/build on your projects, because this should work. I copied your advise class and it has no errors here.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? I'm using 3.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: It is probably not related to the version, but it is 3.2.2.RELEASE with aspectjrt 1.6.11.
If you give me an email address I'll send you a working version with pom.xml